# How to set a relative service reference in Visual Studio?

Tags: wcf, visual-studio

[image]

We have a WCF client and we got the wsdl information in a file. How can I enter a relative URL (to the Visual Studio project) instead of an absolute URL? I tried many forms with no luck, the error message is Invalid URI.

Rationale: Not all developers have checked out the project in the same directory. So it is cumbersome to update the service reference.

Comment: You could put the URL into a config file which each developer could adapt to his needs and create the WCF client-side proxy based on that URL from config. But I don't think you can have *relative* URLs....

Comment: Thanks for your comment. How can I generate the client-side proxy based on an URL in a config file?

Comment: (1) Read the URL from your config, (2) use the appropriate overloaded constructor for your client-side proxy that allows you to explicitly specify a URL for the endpoint

Comment: @marc_s I think you're referring to constructing a proxy object in code, *after* having generated code with the Service Reference dialog. But I might have misunderstood. The OP is talking about using a relative file path in the Service Reference dialog, to avoid having absolute paths in VS project configuration.

Comment: Yes, the question is about visual studio and not about code. If anybody knows a way to set a relative Address in the dialog Service Reverence Settings from visual studio (instead of C:\ggg) like .\blabla.wsdl, then let me know.

Answer (score 1):

What we do in similar scenario is having url pointing to localhost.

Therefore each developer has the service configured in their IIS with same url, something like **http:\localhost...** so config is the same for all.

If this is not an option you might use [Slow Cheetah](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/69023d00-a4f9-4a34-a6cd-7e854ba318b5/) to transfom web.configs (we use it for configs pointing to DEV, QA, Beta, etc.)

Comment: Yes we can publish the wsdl file over tfs and use this as a service reverence address. It is cumbersome anyway since it is not possible to enter relative URLs to project location on harddisk in the address field (see comment from marc_s)